# Converting a WebClient method to async / await

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, async-await

I have some existing code which I am porting to Windows 8 WinRT. The code fetches data from URL, asynchronously invoking a passed delegate:

```
private void RequestData(string uri, Action<string> action)
{
  var client = new WebClient();
  client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) => action(e.Result);
  client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
}
```

Converting to WinRT requires the use of `HttpClient` and asynchronous methods. I've read a few tutorials on async / await, but am a bit baffled. How can I change the method above, but maintain the method signature in order to avoid changing much more of my code?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
private async void RequestData(string uri, Action<string> action)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    string data = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    action(data);
}
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194294.aspx

Comment: The only answer of 5 that shows the whole method and keeps the same signature, so the only one that answers the question. :)

Comment: Thanks - I just knew that it would be something really simple, but couldn't quite get my head around it!

Comment: Just a quick note: Unless you're doing a fire and forget request, change the return type to Task, otherwise the calling thread will just continue the execution regardless if you await RequestData or not

Comment: It is better to use private async Task instead of async void

Comment: Note: the important thing not to miss here is the different method being called : `DownloadString*TASK*Async` vs `DownloadStringAsync`. Because backwards compatibility needed to be retained, a new method needed to be added to the class

Comment: `DownloadStringTaskAsync` is available since .NET 4.5.. Can I achieve this on .NET 4 ?

Comment: @KeyBored Depending on your exact use case, you can try one of the approaches [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vHkRay)

Comment: @ColeCameron Thanks alot .. a late Thank You is better than never :)

Comment: The `async void` return is absolutely wrong for this.

Comment: @bommelding without more context from the question it's hard to say what's right and wrong for this user's exact use case. Generally, yes, `async Task` is preferrable to `async void`, but I opted to try to keep as much the same from the original code snippet as possible (including the "fire and forget" behavior).

Answer (score 11):

> How can I change the method above, but maintain the method signature in order to avoid changing much more of my code?

The best answer is "you don't". If you use `async`, then use it all the way down.

```
private async Task<string> RequestData(string uri)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
  }
}
```

Comment: missing async modifier on method RequestData? :)

Comment: FWIW, in terms of keeping a "pass a callback" signature, Cole's answer seems reasonable IMHO - it's still async, uses await, and invokes the action on the 'right' thread (assuming a synchronization context is in place) AFAICT?  I'll freely admit that passing callbacks like this isn't as nice as having the 'looks synchronous' style of 'normal' async/await code, but if you have existing code accepting callbacks, it seems reasonable to still accept them?  Of course, "async void" is generally a bad idea, so maybe I'm forgetting a problem case here. :)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but I am migrating code, so minimising changes is a priority for me. This is why I want to keep the given signature.

Comment: There are a few problems with `async void`. Unit testing, for one. But most applicable to this case is how it handles errors: any problems with the HTTP download will throw an exception directly on the `SynchronizationContext`, whereas `async Task` permits a more natural handling of exceptions (thrown from the `await`).

Answer (score 8):

Following [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx), you first create the async task wtih, then get its result using `await`:

```
Task<string> downloadStringTask = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(uri));
string result = await downloadStringTask;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var client = new WebClient();
string page = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("url");
```

or

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string page = await client.GetStringAsync("url");
```

Answer (score 3):

`await` the  result of the [HttpClient.GetStringAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746.aspx):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
action(await client.GetStringAsync(uri));
```

Answer (score -1):

And this piece of code is for UploadValuesAsync:

```
public class WebClientAdvanced : WebClient
{
    public async Task<byte[]> UploadValuesAsync(string address, string method, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach (var x in data) nvc.Add(x.Key, x.Value.ToStr());

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
        UploadValuesCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Cancelled) tcs.SetCanceled();
            else if (e.Error != null) tcs.SetException(e.Error);
            else tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
        };

        UploadValuesAsync(new Uri(address), method, nvc);
        var result = await tcs.Task;
        return result;
    }
}
```