# Access MVC Web API from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Following JQuery code gets contacts from local web api. But, I wonder how to call external WEB API from SERVER SIDE?

```
$(function () {
            $.getJSON('/api/contact', function (data) {
                $(data).each(function (i, item) {
                    $('#contacts').append('<li>' + item.Name + '</li>');
                });
            });
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the HttpClient class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the result from the WebApi. This is presuming you are using .Net 4.5 or above.

So your code would look something like;

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
var result = webClient.DownloadString("[YourUrl]");
```

The result is the going to be a Json string, so you would then want to Deserialize the string to an Object.

So if you were to then use Newtonsoft.Json you could deserialize like;

```
MyObject myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get really async fuctionality by calling remote servers from your application, you should use DownloadStringTaskAsync method instead of syncronous DownloadString. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240915/converting-a-webclient-method-to-async-await) is a good question about it.

And example from there:

```
private async void RequestData(string uri, Action<string> action)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    string data = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    action(data);
}
```