# C# Download from url and Custom progress bar

Tags: c#, async-await, visual-studio-2019, webclient

So I made a software that can download strings from url. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {

                    var accounts = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/sample").Split('\n');
                    textBox1.Text = accounts[new Random().Next(0, accounts.Length)];
                }
```

How can I make custom progress bar made by text, such that only text will show for progressing the download? example:

When the download is 10% I want to put on text progressbar (Status: requesting database)

when it comes up to 50% I want to put on text progressbar (Status: getting information)

when it comes 100% (Status: completed)

[My Full Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w21AJ.png)

[My Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwuza.png)

Comment: I think you should use an `async` method for that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240915/converting-a-webclient-method-to-async-await

Comment: i dont understand that you provide example, can you please make a example code including my code? i'm newbie in c#

Comment: See example given in the answer by @divyang4481, it only needs some changes to do what you wish to do, SO is not a writing code service, you have to do some things yourself!

Comment: yeah his code working fine 100% im newbie for c# sorry for asking too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use async method to download

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            Download(new Uri("https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/sample"));
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            Download(new Uri("https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/sample2"));
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            Download(new Uri("https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/sample4"));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "select radio btn");
        }
    }

    private void  Download(Uri uri)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged1;
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += Client_DownloadStringCompleted;
            client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        });
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged1(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            if(percentage >=10 && percentage <50)
            { 
              textBox1.Text ="message for 10%";   
            }
            else if if(percentage >=50 && percentage <100)
            {
                    textBox1.Text ="message for 50%";
            }
            else
            {
              textBox1.Text ="completed";
            }
            // you can use to show to calculated % of download
        });
    }



    private  void Client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            var accounts = e.Result.Split('\n');
            textBox1.Text = accounts[new Random().Next(0,accounts.Length)];
        });
    }
```

Comment: in this method, my pattern is broken, my pattern is get a string from url 1 by 1 and randomize, not all string that I want to get, can you fix your method can you include my pattern

Comment: This doesn’t answer the OP’s question- namely how do you print out the progress of the download

Comment: i want to do is download strings from url 1 by 1 and random strings then when downloading the 1 string from url in put in textbox1

in label1 it should my status whether is completed or downloading

Comment: you should provide your  sample data that you are downloading

Comment: i provide it now, recheck my post i have sample pic

Comment: your code is 100% work now, i have one more question how can i control the DownloadProgress, instead of totalbytes i want to do is text status like logs 


Example: 


when comes to 10% in progress my text status will be Status: blahblahblah instead totalbytes or percentage


when it comes up to 50% it will be Status: blahblahblah


when it comes to 100% it will be Status: blahblahblah

Comment: in that code i have commentted to calculate  percentage value  where you can place logic about if 10% then  something  blalball..

Comment: but why i need progressBar toolbox? i just want is calculate of percentage of downloading and put som logic

Comment: no you do not need  progressbar. you  update you textbox there

Comment: sorry i don't really get it, im really newbie in coding i can't put a logic too, this is the last time that i need your help, can you please provide an example, i'm sorry for too much asking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` has been deprecated in favor of `HttpClient`, but here goes.

You should use `Progress<T>` to report back progress.

You can define an extension method like:

```
public static class WebClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAsync(
        this WebClient webClient,
        string address,
        IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += downloadProgressChanged;
            return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
        }
        finally
        {
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged -= downloadProgressChanged;
        }

        void downloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progress.Report(e.ProgressPercentage);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        var text = await new WebClient()
            .DownloadStringTaskAsync(
                "https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/sample",
                new Progress<int>(p => /* report progress */));
        var accounts = text.Split('\n');
        textBox1.Text = accounts[new Random().Next(0, accounts.Length)];
    }
}
```