# Download file from url and convert to base64 async (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have url where I need to download file and convert to base64 string

I wrote this code to do this

```
private string GetImageAsBase64(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var bytes = client.DownloadData(url);
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

How I can make it async to use returning type `Task<string>`?

Comment: This is kinda similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240915/converting-a-webclient-method-to-async-await

Comment: Mind that Microsoft [discourages the use of WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0#remarks) for new code.

Comment: Okay, so how I can do this without `WebClient` ? @Fildor

Comment: Use HttpClient, which has async APIs, for one. Then you can see how to make the encoding part async.

Comment: @EugeneSukh the remark of the linked article says: "Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class." - big and bold. you basically can't miss it if you read it.

Comment: ^^ In the Question Ryan linked, mind that the accepted answer is not good. Right beneath it, Stephen Cleary gave a much better one (unfortunately using `using HttpClient`, which is of yourse only good for the example and should not be used in production => see IHttpClientFactory and corresponding articles).

Comment: try this 
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetImageAsBase64Async(string url)
{
 using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
 {
  string data = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url)); 
  return  Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
 }
}

Comment: @CooncilWorker If you have an answer, why not write one instead of comment?

Comment: I did not think it was worth an answer - looks like it would have been a near duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are almost there, use the [GetByteArrayAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getbytearrayasync?view=net-5.0):

```cs
private async Task<string> GetImageAsBase64Async(string url) // return Task<string>
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url); // there are other methods if you want to get involved with stream processing etc
        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        return base64String;
    }
}
```

**UPD**

as [@Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) points out, you want to instantiate your [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) once and inject it into the function. A very naive way to do that would be to use an extension method:

```cs
void Main()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // can reuse
    client.GetImageAsBase64("...");
    client.GetImageAsBase64("...");
    client.GetImageAsBase64("...");
}

static class HttpclientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<string> GetImageAsBase64(this HttpClient client, string url)
    {
        var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP: Mind that you should not be using `using (var client = new HttpClient())`. Either have a static HttpClient or use dependency injection (with [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)).

Answer (score -2):

Even if this question is already answered, as written above.

I think you need something like this:

```
 private async Task<string> GetImageAsBase64(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var bytes = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As mentioned above, it better not use WebClient

How I can do this, using HttpClient?

Comment: @EugeneSukh i recommend actually reading [The Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0), since it even contains _code samples_

Comment: _"Even if this question is already answered, as written above."_ - The linked question is not exactly the same and on top: the highly upvoted accepted answer is _bad_ advice from today's standpoint.